# Can I add a rear evaporator in place of my rear heater for my passengers

Tags: ac, hvac, aftermarket-upgrade

I live in a hot climate. I do not need heat to my rear passenger feet. Can I run A/C pipes instead of hot water and replace radiator with an evaporate. The Vehicle is a 1988 Toyota BJ74. The blower unit and radiator are mounted in the rear of the centre console. The hot water running under the car. Will need to bypass those and fit T pieces to A/C run to compressor.

Comment: It sure seems like a reasonable thing to try to do. You'll need to find somebody with the tools and materials to modify the A/C system, so you might also ask them about finding the evaporator that you need. They may be able to tell you if there are any other factors you need to consider. You might need to upgrade the compressor.